# Selenium Hybrid Framework

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

While debugging a java app in eclipse I receive a "Source not found" error in two cases:

The files are there, but eclipse won't step into them, instead it shows a button to "Change attached source"

I have jdk 8 and I try to change attached source but it does not work. Almost I have done any solution which I found in stackoverflow. For more information I have created Hybrid framework for automation with maven dependency and I attached more info.

```
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>hybridFramework</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>hybridFramework</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: your image is missing, please edit the question.

Comment: The properties and/or project tags seem to be wrong position.